# How to deal same method of two catgeory in base class in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I add two category of RegisterViewController. They has same func named djTest. like below:

NewRegisterViewController+TestA.h

```
@interface NewRegisterViewController (TestA)
-(void)djTest;
@end
```

NewRegisterViewController+TestA.m

```
@implementation NewRegisterViewController (TestA)
-(void)djTest{
    NSLog(@"djTest call TestA");
}
@end
```

NewRegisterViewController+TestB.h

```
@interface NewRegisterViewController (TestB)
-(void)djTest;
@end
```

NewRegisterViewController+TestB.m

```
@implementation NewRegisterViewController (TestB)
-(void)djTest{
    NSLog(@"djTest call TestB");
}
@end
```

and In  NewRegisterViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(djTest)]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(djTest)];
    }
}
```

It output "djTest call TestA" in console every time when I run.

My question is :

1. when I didn't import NewRegisterViewController+TestA.h in NewRegisterViewController.m, also the djTest function can be find and perform. so when does this function added in the NewRegisterViewController instance. When class loaded? or the first time using the cagegory or some other time?
2. I import both NewRegisterViewController+TestA.h and NewRegisterViewController+TestB.h, the compiler did give me any warning of multiple djTest function. So how can I avoid the multiple funtion in different category? Always I don't know whether other imply this function.

Comment: It calls function of TestB for me. Not A. See Sample [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ly9n5xq6wraw9qg/CategoryTest.zip?dl=0)

Comment: It is not possible to have two categories with same name in Objective C for a given class. During runtime any one of the methods will be called.

Comment: @iphonic may be it depend on which method add last. So my first question is when it added.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know a bit more about how do categories work.

When you create some class, let's say `MyClass`, you have the pointers to it's method implementations in a class object. The class object is the same for all instances of `MyClass`.

You can manage the class object in runtime via functions that are available in `objc/objc-runtime.h`.

Categories work on exactly similar technology. They just add new methods to your class object. That means, that if you define category, runtime will load all it's method implementations to specified class when the applications starts.

If you define another category for the same class and methods, it just adds the same methods to you object class. In this case it is not possible to determine which implementations your class will contain.

So, categories are all about runtime. And it is not possible to use it in a such manner like you described your questions.

Runtime is not a black box. You can read more about it in documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-126286

Also you can see even the source code of the Objective-C Runtime: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/

Comment: always i didn't use category like my description. but category write by me  may replace category write by others or frameworks. I didn't know whether the had implement it or the method name.

Comment: @qiushuitian You have to check it while writing a code. Just call `respondsToSelector:` on some object to make sure that it does not provide the same method as you want to implement. Another way is to use method prefixes like `ap_someMethod:`, where `ap` is your prefix. This is the way that Apple recommends to Objective-C developers.